# ¿Como acceder a sub elementos en AJAX y jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Bueno estoy trabajando con **AJAX**, **JavaScript** y por supuesto **jQuery**,  he conseguido traer la respuesta de los datos desde la base de datos pudiendo así acceder y mostrar los datos principales de este, el problema va en que no he podido acceder a los elementos hijos que cada padre tiene, no se muy bien como hacerlo, ya he probado varias cosas y me tiene desde ayer atrapado, les dejare mi código para que puedan entender lo que tengo hecho.
Como pueden ver en el *código* consigo los nombres de las categorías padres las despliego con jQuery i*nsertándolas en el HTML* y todo se ve bien, la cosa es y las **sub-categorías**?
**Aqui JSON**

```
[
  {
    "id": "28",
    "name": "Restaurante",
    "activo": "true",
    "sub": [
      {
        "id": "29",
        "name": "Comida Casera"
      },
      {
        "id": "38",
        "name": "Cafetería"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "30",
    "name": "Música",
    "activo": "true",
    "sub": [
      {
        "id": "31",
        "name": "Academia de Música"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "33",
    "name": "Bienstar sexual ",
    "activo": "true",
    "sub": [
      {
        "id": "34",
        "name": "Gel íntimo "
      },
      {
        "id": "66",
        "name": "Juguetes para adultos"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "41",
    "name": "Moda",
    "activo": "true",
    "sub": [
      {
        "id": "40",
        "name": "Mochilas"
      },
      {
        "id": "67",
        "name": "Zapatos Hombre"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "59",
    "name": "Auto",
    "activo": "true",
    "sub": [
      {
        "id": "60",
        "name": "Accesorio para automóviles "
      },
      {
        "id": "61",
        "name": "Lavado para automóviles "
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "63",
    "name": "Belleza",
    "activo": "true",
    "sub": [
      {
        "id": "64",
        "name": "Salón de Belleza"
      },
      {
        "id": "65",
        "name": "Productos de Belleza"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "68",
    "name": "Deporte",
    "activo": "true",
    "sub": [
      {
        "id": "69",
        "name": "Gimnasios"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Aquí el JavaScript.**

```
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://www.kupomcity.com/gamma/api_v2.php?
        _opt=categorias&_act=view',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: null,
        beforeSend: function() {
          //alert('Fetching....');
        },
        success: function() {
          //alert('Fetch Complete');
        },
        error: function() {
          //alert('Error');
        },
        complete: function(data) {   
          var ul = $("<ul class='navbar-nav'>");
          for (var j = 0; j  < data.responseJSON.length ; j++) {
              ul.append("<li class='dropdown'><a href='templates/interior-categoria.html' class='nav-link' data-toggle='dropdown'>" + data.responseJSON[j].name + "<b class='caret'></b></a><ul class='dropdown-menu'><li><a href='templates/interior-categoria.html'>" + data.responseJSON[j].name + "</a></li></ul></li>");
          } 

          $("#categorias").append(ul);   
          if (JSON.stringify(data.statusText) == '"OK"') {
            //$('#cupones_usados').text(JSON.stringify(data.responseJSON));
            //alert("cupones: " +JSON.stringify(data.responseJSON));
          }
        }
      });
```

Comment: Seria bueno que pusieras el Json con su contenido para poder guiarnos seria de ayuda

Comment: Quieres obtener el contenido de las subcategorias ?

Comment: Ya esta la edición donde se muestra la composición de Json en cuestión, para que lo analicen.

Comment: Y si quiero obtener el contenido de las subcategorias @JavierAntonioAguayoAguilar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este código se puede trabajar , para hacerlo mas dinamico , pero es para que te hagas una idea.

```js
var responseJSON = [
  {
    "id": "28",
    "name": "Restaurante",
    "activo": "true",
    "sub": [
      {
        "id": "29",
        "name": "Comida Casera"
      },
      {
        "id": "38",
        "name": "Cafetería"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "30",
    "name": "Música",
    "activo": "true",
    "sub": [
      {
        "id": "31",
        "name": "Academia de Música"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "33",
    "name": "Bienstar sexual ",
    "activo": "true",
    "sub": [
      {
        "id": "34",
        "name": "Gel íntimo "
      },
      {
        "id": "66",
        "name": "Juguetes para adultos"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "41",
    "name": "Moda",
    "activo": "true",
    "sub": [
      {
        "id": "40",
        "name": "Mochilas"
      },
      {
        "id": "67",
        "name": "Zapatos Hombre"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "59",
    "name": "Auto",
    "activo": "true",
    "sub": [
      {
        "id": "60",
        "name": "Accesorio para automóviles "
      },
      {
        "id": "61",
        "name": "Lavado para automóviles "
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "63",
    "name": "Belleza",
    "activo": "true",
    "sub": [
      {
        "id": "64",
        "name": "Salón de Belleza"
      },
      {
        "id": "65",
        "name": "Productos de Belleza"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "68",
    "name": "Deporte",
    "activo": "true",
    "sub": [
      {
        "id": "69",
        "name": "Gimnasios"
      }
    ]
  }
];


for (var i=0 ; i<1; i++) {
    $.each(responseJSON, function (ind, elem) {
  console.log(elem.sub[i]);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ojo! tu accedes a la propiedad `name` de esta manera

```
data.responseJSON[j].name
```

Por lo tanto deberias acceder a `sub` asi :

```
data.responseJSON[j].sub
```

Sub, es un arreglo con objetos con el formato :

```
{ id : '', name : '' }
```

por lo tanto deberias recorrerlo para obtener las subcategorias.

```
for (var s = 0; s  < data.responseJSON[j].sub.length ; s++) {
     var subcategoria = data.responseJSON[j].sub[s];
     /* Acceder a sus propiedades
     subcategoria.id
     subcategoria.name */
```

Podrias tambien ocupar un `forEach` para asi potenciar el uso del jquery

```js
var json = [
  {
    "id": "28",
    "name": "Restaurante",
    "activo": "true",
    "sub": [
      {
        "id": "29",
        "name": "Comida Casera"
      },
      {
        "id": "38",
        "name": "Cafetería"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "30",
    "name": "Música",
    "activo": "true",
    "sub": [
      {
        "id": "31",
        "name": "Academia de Música"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "33",
    "name": "Bienstar sexual ",
    "activo": "true",
    "sub": [
      {
        "id": "34",
        "name": "Gel íntimo "
      },
      {
        "id": "66",
        "name": "Juguetes para adultos"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "41",
    "name": "Moda",
    "activo": "true",
    "sub": [
      {
        "id": "40",
        "name": "Mochilas"
      },
      {
        "id": "67",
        "name": "Zapatos Hombre"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "59",
    "name": "Auto",
    "activo": "true",
    "sub": [
      {
        "id": "60",
        "name": "Accesorio para automóviles "
      },
      {
        "id": "61",
        "name": "Lavado para automóviles "
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "63",
    "name": "Belleza",
    "activo": "true",
    "sub": [
      {
        "id": "64",
        "name": "Salón de Belleza"
      },
      {
        "id": "65",
        "name": "Productos de Belleza"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "68",
    "name": "Deporte",
    "activo": "true",
    "sub": [
      {
        "id": "69",
        "name": "Gimnasios"
      }
    ]
  }
];
$.each(json, function (ind, elem) {
  $.each(elem.sub, function (i, subcategoria) {
    console.log("Subcategoria : " + subcategoria.name);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias, tu solución me ha dado el resultado que buscaba, ahora podre completar lo que me faltaba y seguir adelante con el proyecto, me has sacado de un apuro.

Comment: @NelsonJaraTorres actualice mi respuesta para que pudieses ocupar un foreach, te ahorras codigo y ocuparas bien jquery :). Sacaste mi respuesta jajaja :D

Answer (score 0):

Como regla general, todo lo que en un JSON tiene corchetes es un **array**, y podés acceder con corchetes, y todo lo que en un JSON tiene llaves es un **objeto**, y podés acceder con notación de punto.

Asumiendo este JSON:

```
var json = JSON.parse('[{"id":28, "name":"Carlos", "surname":"Gomez"}]');
```

Podés acceder al apellido así:

```
var apellido = json[0].surname; // "Gomez"
```

Tené en cuenta que de acuerdo con el JSON que copypasteaste, todo el contenido está dentro del primer elemento de un array, así que hagas lo que hagas, empezá con variable[0].

Por ejemplo, para acceder al objeto que en tu ejemplo dice "comida casera":

```
var id = variable[0].sub[0].id; // "29"
var nombre = variable[0].sub[0].name; // "Comida casera"
```